# Libsvm vs Weka (WLSVM)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka, svm, libsvm

I've got to deal with an unbalanced dataset (95% record of negative class and 5% positive). I developed a model using decision tree and [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) framework. Now I'd like to try SVM and Libsvm to get better results. I'm trying to use [Libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for matlab an [Libsvm weka wrapper](http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM). I'd like to know how to compare results that I get from them. In weka a model is built from the whole dataset and after a 10-fold cross validation is performed. How can I do it with Libsvm? From [Libsvm FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html)'s I discovered that CV is made only to discover best parameters for kernels,not during train/predict, so what is the exact sequence of action that I should do in Matlab to obtain similar results in order to compare them with Weka?

Comment: If you built a decision tree in Weka and you are trying to compare with that, why don't you just use libsvm in weka?  Why are you using Matlab?

The cross-validation done by libsvm is the same idea, its just that it is all done in the svm-train executable.  The executables all call into a common code set.

Comment: Because I read that Libsvm on Matlab is more suitable for my problem. Anyway in Libsvm cross validation can be done only to find good parameters, so before the training phase. But i can't use it as in weka, I mean I can't use during the prediction/validation phase. So I don't know if I can compare the results.

Comment: Weka and Matlab are just front end interfaces to the same code, libsvm.  The info you are reading on the libsvm FAQ is for using libsvm's own command line interface.  Yes, if you tell libsvm to do cross validation, you can't use the model to then call svm_predict.  This is because you have actually built 10 models (or however many folds for cv you chose).  If you run libsvm in Weka, Weka will do the cross-validation and libsvm will just be run on each dataset weka creates.  If you want to do it in Matlab you'll have to divide your data into the n-folds for CV yourself.